# Is Microsoft AVRO able to serialize ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, hadoop, serialization, avro, concurrentdictionary

I'm trying to use the `Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro` library to do serialization. But it fails to serialize the `ConcurrentDictionary` type. It treats `ConcurrentDictionary` as a regular `Dictionary` and looks for the `Add` method. Of course it doesn't exist.

Did I miss some settings? I had to explicitly set "allowNullable" to true to allow a string to be null......

Or how can I extend the serializer? I didn't find any information about this, either. I know it's open source but I don't want to touch the library code, just extend it.

EDIT:
An example class:

```
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class CacheItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheItemEntity> _cacheItemDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheItemEntity>();

        ......
    }
```

EDIT at 16/04/2015:
For people who are interested, Microsoft AVRO library does not support ConcurrentDictionary to this date. And there is not confirmed plan to support it in the near future.

Comment: Your best option may be (if possible in your scenario) to use a dictionary as an intermediate purely for serialization purposes. Perhaps it is possible to create your own data contract resolver or implementation of `AvroContractResolver` for this. Could you provide an example class including `[DataContract]` annotations for one of the classes you are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

No Chance  , for things on the wire /ipc  i tend to go simple types array , string , byte  etc even Datetime and ulong can give issues which you waste a lot of time hunting down.